# Possibility of Life in a solar system given these conditions?

Tags: worldbuilding-process, solar-system

**Scenario**

I’m creating a fictional world and I wanted it to be semi-realistic and I’m starting out by creating the Solar system and while I am no astronomer I did some research and found that K-type stars are the best stars for supporting complex life given their lifespan and relative brightness & temperature but I originally planned for the solar system to be a close binary star system so a planet could exist given that its in the habitable zone far from the stars.

Question is would it be possible for life to survive in a solar system like this? (Answers can be scientifically explained, I just wanted to make sure this world can be relatively realistic)

Answer (score 2):

### We can't know for sure, but go with it if that's what you like!

In order to make solid statements about life, we need to find multiple inhabited worlds.  Otherwise, it's guesswork.  We know circumbinary planets are possible and that orange dwarf stars can be stable and bright; beyond that, who knows what is best for life?

Guesswork has a place - your desire for a firm scientific foundation is commendable!  But guesses *change*.  For a few years, people lamented that the worlds of TRAPPIST-1 would be stripped of water by the flares of the red dwarf star.  Then it was reported that several were [deluged in water](https://www.space.com/41714-water-rich-exoplanets-trappist-1-system.html), and fears were that everything else would be inaccessible under a world ocean and ice.

Great classic science fiction needs to follow some professional source; it doesn't need to be *right*.  For example, Niven's "The Coldest Place", set on the mythical dark side of Mercury, is a memorable landmark of sci-fi because it *could* have been realistic, even if the data didn't hold up.

So long as you like the source that inspired you to go this way, don't be deterred.

P.S. According to the Wikipedia article the other answer links, the planets need to be 2-4 times further from the stars than the stars are from one another.  But this is no issue, since the stars will look prettiest if on the verge of touching.  Alternatively, planets at the inner limit which have existential orbital concerns can make a good backdrop for epic space fiction.

Comment: Thank I very much appreciate your answer and I will take that into consideration so I don’t overwhelm myself in the world buried process THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is Wikipedia so it's not the most reliable source, but it says that scientifically, it is probably possible, which makes sense. Life can survive in so many places (take the animals that live at the bottom of the ocean and survive through chemosynthesis) that I would think it's quite likely that it could evolve to live on a planet in your system.

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to include the link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitability_of_binary_star_systems

Comment: Thanks I will look more into it so I have a better basis for this solar system Thanks!!!